# ODP.NET Oracle Data Adapter Fails to Fill Dataset

Tags: .net, vb.net, oracle11g, odp.net

Hi there I have problem with a function designed to return data from a table in an Oracle 11 database.  I am using an OracleDataAdapter to populate a dataset, in this instance, the code fails to populate the dataset, despite the fact that there is data in the table.  No exception is generated by the code, its as if the code thinks the table is empty.  Overriding the SQL in the function to return data from a different table successfully returns data to the dataset.  This is driving me insane, it makes no sense.  Here is the function:

```
    Public Overridable Function GetData(ByVal sqlStatement As String) As DataSet

    Dim myConnection As New OracleConnection
    Dim myCommand As OracleCommand = Nothing
    Dim myDataAdapter As OracleDataAdapter
    Dim myDataSet As New DataSet

    myConnection = New OracleConnection
    myConnection.ConnectionString = _connectStr

    If sqlStatement = "" Then
        sqlStatement = "SELECT ID, TEXT " & _
            "FROM P_TBL_DEVICECATEGORY"
    End If

    Try
        myDataAdapter = New OracleDataAdapter(sqlStatement, myConnection)
        myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "DeviceCategory")
        myConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    Finally
        CType(myConnection, IDisposable).Dispose()
    End Try
    Return myDataSet

End Function
```

This code is tried and trusted on multiple other tables in the database over the past 10 years, its just returning data from this table that is the issue.  Here is the results of the SQL listed in the function as executed from SQLDeveloper:

"ID","TEXT","CHANGEDBYID","CHANGEDON"
"1","GMCB","1","31-JAN-17"
"2","PMCB","1","31-JAN-17"
"3","GMSW","1","31-JAN-17"
"4","PMSW","1","31-JAN-17"

Any assistance much appreciated.

Kind Regards
Paul J.

Comment: Are you sure the string _sqlStatement_ is empty or contains the correct query? If you use the debugger what is the value of the string after the if check?

Comment: Yep the sqlStatement variable is definitely populated with the correct SQL statement.

Comment: The most direct attack on a problem like this is to use ODP.NET tracing to watch the actual SQL that is being used to make sure it is expected and if it isn't it may shed light. SQLNET tracing is harder to read but it will also help also if you can't get ODP.NET tracing to work. I will dig around for some instructions on how to turn these on.

Comment: Once you are certain the right SQL is being used, another suggestion is to try to execute and fetch that SQL statement without using a DataAdapter to see if that gives different results. And make sure that the database and schema being connected to is as expected and the same as SQLDeveloper. (Make sure you know which TNSNAMES.ORA each are using and look inside each) Finally keep in mind that in it's default state, ODP.NET does significant caching, so make sure that this table is not being emptied or dropped while you are testing this and start your test with a newly opened connection.

Comment: @Paul Johnson, I am also facing the same issue with one of my tables. Did you get any solution for your issue? It will be lot helpful. Surprisingly, it is working with all other tables except one & the one is not so different from other tables